# How to detect kafka record reaching its TTL

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to detect a kafka message reaching its time to live (about ten minutes in my case) to automate some actions.

Is there any ways to make this happen ?

Thanks !
Kev'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in mechanism or metrics for this beyond starting a consumer with some random group, with `auto.offset.reset=earliest`, then consuming the first records of a topic, then inspecting its record timestamp. However, in high throughput systems with thousands of messages per second, in the time to start a consumer instance, some records could already be falling out.

Even then, that's only a *best guess* because only closed segments are deleted. Records/messages themselves don't have TTL. So, in reality, SSHing to the brokers and dumping old segments would find out exactly which records (segments) are about to be removed

Comment: Okay, so with this kind of solutions we're iterating over all the topics' records right ? I was thinking about this kind of solution but wanted to see if I could avoid that CPU usage in case of a very active topic. But sadly as you said I don't think we can

Comment: You can always limit the number of messages if using the consumer approach. Otherwise, log segment dump cli command would only be used on the earliest available segment, which has a default max size of about 1Gb